# how to pivot when there are many columns

Tags: sql, t-sql, pivot-table

I think I understand the concept of PIVOT, but I am having a lot of trouble converting this query into a PIVOT:

```
SELECT ID,
CASE WHEN [line] = "1" THEN code ELSE            "" AS one_CODE,
CASE WHEN [line] = "1" THEN name ELSE            "" AS one_NAME,
CASE WHEN [line] = "1" THEN address_line_1 ELSE  "" AS one_ADDRESS_LINE_1,
CASE WHEN [line] = "1" THEN address_line_2 ELSE  "" AS one_ADDRESS_LINE_2,
CASE WHEN [line] = "1" THEN address_city ELSE    "" AS one_ADDRESS_CITY,
CASE WHEN [line] = "1" THEN address_state ELSE   "" AS one_ADDRESS_STATE,
CASE WHEN [line] = "1" THEN address_zip ELSE     "" AS one_ADDRESS_ZIP,
CASE WHEN [line] = "2" THEN code ELSE            "" AS two_CODE,
CASE WHEN [line] = "2" THEN name ELSE            "" AS two_NAME,
CASE WHEN [line] = "2" THEN address_line_1 ELSE  "" AS two_ADDRESS_LINE_1,
CASE WHEN [line] = "2" THEN address_line_2 ELSE  "" AS two_ADDRESS_LINE_2,
CASE WHEN [line] = "2" THEN address_city ELSE    "" AS two_ADDRESS_CITY,
CASE WHEN [line] = "2" THEN address_state ELSE   "" AS two_ADDRESS_STATE,
CASE WHEN [line] = "2" THEN address_zip ELSE     "" AS two_ADDRESS_ZIP,
CASE WHEN [line] = "3" THEN code ELSE            "" AS three_CODE,
CASE WHEN [line] = "3" THEN name ELSE            "" AS three_NAME,
CASE WHEN [line] = "3" THEN address_line_1 ELSE  "" AS three_ADDRESS_LINE_1,
CASE WHEN [line] = "3" THEN address_line_2 ELSE  "" AS three_ADDRESS_LINE_2,
CASE WHEN [line] = "3" THEN address_city ELSE    "" AS three_ADDRESS_CITY,
CASE WHEN [line] = "3" THEN address_state ELSE   "" AS three_ADDRESS_STATE,
CASE WHEN [line] = "3" THEN address_zip ELSE     "" AS three_ADDRESS_ZIP
FROM MYTABLE
```

**Desired result:**

```
+----+----------+----------+--------------------+--------------------+------------------+-------------------+-----------------+------------+------------+--------------------+--------------------+------------------+-------------------+-----------------+---------------+------------+----------------------+----------------------+--------------------+---------------------+-------------------+
| ID | one_CODE | one_NAME | one_ADDRESS_LINE_1 | one_ADDRESS_LINE_2 | one_ADDRESS_CITY | one_ADDRESS_STATE | one_ADDRESS_ZIP |  two_CODE  |  two_NAME  | two_ADDRESS_LINE_1 | two_ADDRESS_LINE_2 | two_ADDRESS_CITY | two_ADDRESS_STATE | two_ADDRESS_ZIP |  three_CODE   | three_NAME | three_ADDRESS_LINE_1 | three_ADDRESS_LINE_2 | three_ADDRESS_CITY | three_ADDRESS_STATE | three_ADDRESS_ZIP |
+----+----------+----------+--------------------+--------------------+------------------+-------------------+-----------------+------------+------------+--------------------+--------------------+------------------+-------------------+-----------------+---------------+------------+----------------------+----------------------+--------------------+---------------------+-------------------+
|  1 | a        | b        | c                  | d                  |                  |                   |                 | bluecross  | blueshield |                    |                    |                  |                   |                 |               |            |                      |                      |                    |                     |                   |
|  2 | anthem   | myerland | 234                |                    |                  |                   |                 |            |            |                    |                    |                  |                   |                 |               |            |                      |                      |                    |                     |                   |
|  3 | anthem   | b        | 234 albin          |                    |                  |                   |                 | blueshield |            |                    |                    |                  |                   |                 | hartford life |            |                      |                      |                    |                     |                   |
+----+----------+----------+--------------------+--------------------+------------------+-------------------+-----------------+------------+------------+--------------------+--------------------+------------------+-------------------+-----------------+---------------+------------+----------------------+----------------------+--------------------+---------------------+-------------------+
```

**How do I output just 1 record for each ID?**

Comment: Use an aggregate function, like `max(case when ...`

Comment: See if my answer helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use aggregation:

```
select id,
       MAX(CASE WHEN [line] = 1 THEN code END) AS one_CODE,
       MAX(CASE WHEN [line] = 1 THEN name END) AS one_NAME,
       . . .
from t
group by id;
```

Notes:

- SQL Server uses double quotes to delimit identifiers, not strings.  Double quotes are not needed for this query.
- Something called `line` is probably a number, so the comparison value should be a number.
- This returns `NULL` instead of an empty string.
- I see no benefit to trying to use `pivot` for this query.

Answer (score 1):

If you can tolerate the performance, look up `CHOOSE` function. I've implemented it below.

```
    SELECT ID,
    MAX(CHOOSE([line],code)) AS one_CODE,
    MAX(CHOOSE([line],name)) AS one_name,
    MAX(CHOOSE([line],address_line_1)) AS one_address_[line]_1 ,
    MAX(CHOOSE([line],address_line_2)) AS one_address_[line]_2,
    MAX(CHOOSE([line],address_city)) AS one_address_city ,
    MAX(CHOOSE([line],address_state)) AS one_address_state,
    MAX(CHOOSE([line],address_zip)) AS one_address_zip ,
    MAX(CHOOSE([line]-1,code)) AS two_CODE,
    MAX(CHOOSE([line]-1,name)) AS two_name,
    MAX(CHOOSE([line]-1,address_line_1)) AS two_address_[line]_1 ,
    MAX(CHOOSE([line]-1,address_line_2)) AS two_address_[line]_2,
    MAX(CHOOSE([line]-1,address_city)) AS two_address_city,
    MAX(CHOOSE([line]-1,address_state)) AS two_address_state,
    MAX(CHOOSE([line]-1,address_zip)) AS two_address_zip,
    MAX(CHOOSE([line]-2,code)) AS three_CODE,
    MAX(CHOOSE([line]-2,name)) AS three_name,
    MAX(CHOOSE([line]-2,address_line_1)) AS three_address_[line]_1 ,
    MAX(CHOOSE([line]-2,address_line_2)) AS three_address_[line]_2,
    MAX(CHOOSE([line]-2,address_city)) AS three_address_city,
    MAX(CHOOSE([line]-2,address_state)) AS three_address_state,
    MAX(CHOOSE([line]-2,address_zip)) AS three_address_zip
    FROM MYTABLE
    GROUP BY ID;
```

Answer (score 1):

How about a nice self join, before I dive into the answer I'll just state my assumption up front, you have 7 columns in the table, plus the key ID that relates the rows. if that's the case all you have to do is

```
select a.ID
  , a.CODE as one_code
  , a.name as One_name
  , a.address_line_1 as one_address_line_1
  , a.ADDRESS_LINE_2 as one_ADDRESS_LINE_2
  , a.City as One_city
  , a.state as One_state
  , a.zip as one_zip
  , a.CODE as one_code
  , b.name as two_name
  , b.address_line_1 as two_address_line_1
  , b.ADDRESS_LINE_2 as two_ADDRESS_LINE_2
  , b.City as two_city
  , b.state as two_state
  , b.zip as two_zip
  , c.name as three_name
  , c.address_line_1 as three_address_line_1
  , c.ADDRESS_LINE_2 as three_ADDRESS_LINE_2
  , c.City as three_city
  , c.state as three_state
  , c.zip as three_zip
from mytable a
  left outer join mytable b on a.id = b.id and b.line = 2
  left outer join mytable c on c.id = a.id and c.line = 3
where a.line = 1
```

So what we are doing is called a self join, because all three of the sets of data are in the same table, so we alias the rows with different line values as separate tables and then left outer join them. We use a left outer join since it appears only that line 1 is required, and line 2 and 3 are optional. Hope this helps :)

Comment: You're still left with the same number of rows as before in the left table though